# Site accepting cross-site XHTMLRequest should always require XSRF security?

Tags: csrf, xmlhttprequest

If a server accepts cross site XHTMLRequests (access-control-allow-origin), shouldn't the server enforce a protection against cross site request forgery (CSRF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Generally speaking, if the request causes permanent changes, and you don't want people arbitrarily causing changes, CSRF protection is highly advised.

Answer (score 1):

The server should not enforce that but the application should, whenever it has critical operations done via a non human validated (i.e CAPTCHA) request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should always protect against CSRF in general.